# I want to save device battery status details to firebase when every time user sign in and sign out in app IONIC 3

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, ionic-native

I can get battery status using Battery

```
getBatteryStatus() {
    // watch change in battery status
    this.subscription = this.oBatteryStatus.onChange().subscribe(
      (status: BatteryStatusResponse) => {
        this.currentBatteryLevel = status.level;
        this.currentBatteryIsPlugged = status.isPlugged;

        this.oUser_log_model.user_id = this.loggedInUserId;
        this.oUser_log_model.user_device_battery_status = this.currentBatteryLevel;
        this.oUser_log_model.user_device_battery_is_plugged = this.currentBatteryIsPlugged;

        this.oAngularFireDatabase.database.ref('User_Log').set(this.oUser_log_model).then(() => {
          let toast3 = this.oToastController.create({
            message: 'Successfully Saved..',
            duration: 3000,
            position: 'top',
            cssClass: 'dark-trans',
            closeButtonText: 'OK',
            showCloseButton: true
          });
          toast3.present();
        })

      });
  }
```

if i call this function on button click event it is working fine. but i want call this function every time user login to app and logout from app .I have tried to call this `getBatteryStatus()` function in `initializeApp()` function.but it is not saving battery status to firebase.

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
     // I HAVE  TRIED TO CALL GET BATTERY STATUS FUNCTION FROM HERE
      // watch network for a disconnect
      let disconnectSubscription = this.oNetwork.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
        let toast = this.oToastController.create({
          message: 'You are offline ..',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top',
          cssClass: 'dark-trans',
          closeButtonText: 'OK',
          showCloseButton: true
        });
        toast.present();
      });

      // watch network for a connection
      let connectSubscription = this.oNetwork.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
        let toast = this.oToastController.create({
          message: 'Get back to online .. ',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top',
          cssClass: 'dark-trans',
          closeButtonText: 'OK',
          showCloseButton: true
        });
        toast.present();
        // We just got a connection but we need to wait briefly
        // before we determine the connection type. Might need to wait.
        // prior to doing any api requests as well.
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (this.oNetwork.type === 'wifi') {
            let toast = this.oToastController.create({
              message: 'Connected to the wifi',
              duration: 3000,
              position: 'top',
              cssClass: 'dark-trans',
              closeButtonText: 'OK',
              showCloseButton: true
            });
            toast.present();
          }
        }, 3000);
      });
      // this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
```

Comment: If you leave your app by just pressing the home button, and then come back to the app `initializeApp()`  will not trigger, since the app is in background. What do you mean by "login to app" and "logout from app" ?

Comment: i want to get battery status when user doing all these things. when pressing home button and logout and login and etc. @saperlipopette

Comment: the `initializeApp()` function is triggered only when you launch your app. So if you put your code to send the battery status in this function, the battery status will be sent to firebase only at app startup. You should make a function sending the battery status, and launch this function whenever you want.